# how to call function where parameter based on a promise

Tags: node.js, promise

had following code which worked:

```
let sdk = new SDK({ name: "somevalue"});

module.exports= ()=> {
  sdk.dothing();
}
```

I then needed to change the parameter to use data from an async function:

```
let asyncfunc = require('asyncfunc');

let sdk = new SDK({ name: (()=>{ 
    return asyncfunc()
        .then((data) => { 
            return data.value
        })
    });

module.exports= ()=> {
  sdk.dothing();
}
```

Following the change, the call to new SDK is failing because the parameter passed is {} as the asyncFunc promise has not yet resolved.

I'm getting back into node after a year and new to promises. what is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've found, you can't pass in a promise to something that's expecting a string. You need to wait for the asynchronous operation to complete.

This means that your SDK won't be ready right away, so you have two options:

1. Change your module so it returns a promise for the needed value. Anyone who needs to use your module would need to use the returned promise.

Example:

```
let pSdk = asyncFunc()
    .then(data => new SDK({ name: data.value }));

module.exports = () => pSdk.then(sdk => sdk.dothing());
```

2. Store an `sdk` value that's not populated immediately. Users of your module can obtain the SDK instance directly, but it might not be ready when they need it.

Example:

```
let sdk;

asyncFunc()
    .then(data => sdk = new SDK({ name: data.value }));

module.exports = () => {
    if(!sdk) { throw new Error("The SDK is not ready yet!"); }
    return sdk.dothing();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

if any bit of code, in node, is asynchronous then immediately next bit of code will be executed. it doesn't matter if the asynchronous code is wrapped in promise or not.( For codes wrapped in the promise the compiler will return a pending promise to be resoled or rejected and proceed to the next bit of code.) When you are creating an object using `new SDK({ })` the name is having reference to a pending promise which is yet to be settled that's why your code is failing to fulfill your requirement. You can do it this way to resolve your problem.

```
asyncfunc()
   .then((data) => { 
        return new SDK({ name: data.value });
}).then(function(sdk){
    //do your work here using sdk
})
```

One important point to be noted here is you can't return from `.then()` to assign the value to any variable as you are doing. The value returned from `.then()` will be accessible from the next chained `.then()` not by outside global variable.**Since you are exporting `sdk.dothing()` so you need to export it inside the last `.then()`**